# Data cannot GET by REST API

Tags: parse-platform

I use curl to query data from Parse, like this:

```
 curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxxxxxxxxx" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxxxxx" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TestObject
```

and it always return `{"results":[]}`. But I could GET 'https://api.parse.com/1/users' successfully.

Comment: Do you have any TestObjects? Saying a request for one thing doesn't work and a request for a different thing does isn't much info about the problem

Comment: It's due to the security on ACL, I set the ACL as read/write by its owner.